# How i can have counter in xquery?

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

I am using XQuery in exist-db and I want to use a counter. For example I have this code :

```
xquery version "3.0";
for $P in 1 to 351
  let $S := data(doc(concat('/db/INDEX/' , $P , '.html'))//h1)
    for $result in $S
     return <a class="libraryIndexlink" href="http://library.net/newindex.aspx?pid=102834&amp;BookID=106201&amp;PageIndex={$P}&amp;Language=1#p0">{$result}</a>
```

I need that after `Language=1#p` the counter variable follows. For example:

```
Language=1#p0">

Language=1#p1">

Language=1#p2">
```

I write this codes:

```
declare function local:prod2ndDigit() {
    for $x in (0 to 10)
        return <counter>{$x}</counter>
};
local:prod2ndDigit()
```

This code works, but has a logical error.
My other code is:

```
declare function local:prod2ndDigit() {
  declare variable $C := 0
  return $C := $C + 1
};
local:prod2ndDigit()
```

This code does not work.

The final code is:

```
declare function local:prod2ndDigit() {
    for $x in (0 to 10)
        return <counter>{$x}</counter>
};

for $P in 1 to 351
  let $S := data(doc(concat('/db/INDEX/' , $P , '.html'))//h1)
    for $result in $S
     return <a class="libraryIndexlink" href="http://library.net/newindex.aspx?pid=102834&amp;BookID=106201&amp;PageIndex={$P}&amp;Language=1#plocal:prod2ndDigit()">{$result}</a>
```

But this code seems to have a logical error.
I write this code but it returns `false` instead of an integer:

```
let $C := 0
    return
        $C = $C + 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic you are using does not apply to a functional programming language like XQuery. I guess you want to iterate over each `h1` element and want to include an increasing counter. This is actually even simpler than you probably imagined:

```
for $result at $key in data(doc(concat('/db/INDEX/' , $P , '.html'))//h1)
return <a class="libraryIndexlink" href="http://library.net/newindex.aspx?pid=102834&amp;BookID=106201&amp;PageIndex={$P}&amp;Language=1#p{$key - 1}">{$result}</a>
```

The `at $key` statement gives you the position, i.e. the counter you want. As it seems you want to start with 0, but in XQuery sequences always start at position 1, hence we use the `- 1`

There are a couple of other things wrong in your code. You will have to put XQuery function calls or variables into curly braces, what you did do for `$P`, but not for `local:prod2ndDigit()`.

That the code `let $C := 0 return $C = $C + 1` returns `false` is correct. You are using the `=` operator, which does mean equal in XQuery. You probably intended to write an assignment, which the operator for is `:=`. Also, it seems like you want to increase the counter. Keep in mind that XQuery is a functional language, as I said before, so you can **never manipulate a variable** You will always create a new `$counter` variable and shadow the old value, but you can not change the variable as you do in other languages like C, Java, Python and so on and so forth.

I don't have any idea what you want to achieve with your function `local:prod2ndDigit()`. It returns a sequence of items, but I do not see the use case here.

Comment: What exactly do you want? This is quite unclear from your question. This will return an element like you have given above for each `h1` element in your doc. Could you please expand your question with some expected output and if necessary same example input document? Otherwise it is difficult to guess what you want - I tried to guess, but seems like it is not what you want.

Comment: I need enumerate `h1` and write the number front P .

Comment: You absolutely **need** to describe your problem better. What you said now is exactly what my code does, so it seems you want something different. Please give **concrete** example output for some example input!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dirkk . I manipulate your answer and get the correct answer:
Very very thanks....

```
xquery version "3.0";
for $P in 1 to 351
for $result at $key in data(doc(concat('/db/INDEX/' , $P , '.html'))//h1)
return <a class="libraryIndexlink" href="http://library.net/newindex.aspx?pid=102834&amp;BookID=106201&amp;PageIndex={$P}&amp;Language=1#p{$key - 2+$P}">{$result}</a>
```